# Reset an alert from smartd when there is no longer a problem

Tags: monitoring, smart

Ubuntu 22.04. I've installed smartmontools, and added a script to /etc/smartmontools/run.d that writes any problem reports to a file where they can get picked up by our alerting system.

I want to also automatically delete these problem report files when smartd no longer detects a problem (preferably per disk), but of course smartd only runs the scripts in that directory when there is a problem. Is there some hook I can use to detect when it runs to delete all such files just before? Or another way to do this?